# JQuery event onclick to show/hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please, can you help? I have some HTML:

> ```
> <span class="about" id="but01">About this</span>
>
> <span class="about" id="but02">About this</span>
>
> <div id="s1" class="hidden">
> <div id="s2" class="hidden">
> ```

and I need to call div id s1/s2 hidden/show with onclick event from span id but01/but02 using JQuery.

Thx to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is pretty simple solution:

```
$("#but01").click( function () {
  $("#s1").toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tt36q/9/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('span[id^="but0"]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(4);
    if($('#s' + id).is(':visible'))
         $('#s' + id).hide();
    else
        $('#s' + id).show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b6cFA/)

Answer (score 0):

This used the on function:

```
$("#but01").on('click', function () {
  $("#s1").toggle();
});
```

Comment: This will bind function to dynamically created elements also.